# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt a_n}{n^p}$ diverges, then p $\in$ {?}

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let {$a_n$} be a sequence of non-negative real numbers such that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ is convergent.

If p is a real number such that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt a_n}{n^p}$$
diverges, then what can be said about the value of p?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756510/convergence-of-sum-frac-sqrta-nnp

Answer (score 5):

By the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) we have
$$\sum_1^N \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^p}\le \left(\sum_1^N a_n\right) \left(\sum_1^N \frac{1}{n^{2p}}\right).$$
The sum on the left is unbounded, and therefore $\sum_1^N \frac{1}{n^{2p}}$ is unbounded. It follows that $p\le 1/2$.

**Remark:** We cannot strengthen the inequality  to $p\lt 1/2$. For if $n\ge 2$, let $a_n=\frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$. Then $\sum a_n$ converges, and $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^{1/2}}$ diverges.

Comment: If we take $a_n=\dfrac{1}{n^{1.04}} \implies \sqrt a_n=\dfrac{1}{n^{0.52}}. p=1/2$ will not work here

Answer (score 4):

Seems like we'll have to make use of the A.M. $\ge$ G.M. inequality here, so that we have $$\frac {\sqrt{a_n}} {n^p} \leq a_n + \frac{1}{n^{2p}}$$
Now, this diverges for p $\le$ $\frac12$. So that must be the required answer.

Can anyone show how to do this using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality? It is simple I reckon.:)

Comment: Using AM/GM is a nice idea, better than my more routine Cauchy-Schwarz.