# Convergence of a series (using the comparation test ?)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'll be glad to get some help in this one :)

$a_n>0$ i a sequence such that the series $\sum a_n$ converges.
Prove that the series $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ converges.
I thought of using the comparation test but thats it.

I'm sorry I didn't know how to write the sigma letter for series :/

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756510/convergence-of-sum-frac-sqrta-nnp

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/795481/117818

Answer (score 1):

Regard the partial sums as inner products and use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.